Name of an 80's fight to death movie
For several years now I've been searching for a movie my father used to have on VHS. I believe it's from the 80's but could be late 70's or early 90's.
The main character, a cop, and his friend who is also a cop, enter a fight to the death match with other participants. I can't remember exactly why they enter this fight, nut t might have had something to do with something happening to the wife of one of the cops and them wanting revenge.  However, his reasons do revolve around wanting to fight this huge guy that has curly hair (maybe blonde).
The fights are all indoors in some kind of arena, and if the fight takes too long a bell rings and weapons are given to them. The weapons could be knives, katanas, swords. During one fight the four sides of a cage lowers from the top and they fight the match in a metal cage.
When the good guy gets to fight the villain something happens and the fight doesn't finish and the final fight scene takes place in some kind of subterraneous parking lot or a construction building where the bad guy is  decapitated. I can still see his head rolling on the floor with his curly hair.

Sounds like something Jean-Claude Van Damme would have starred in, although I can't find any good matches for the details provided.

My first thought was a best of the best movie and then the end scene of The Running Man. There's even an episode of Angel that might do the trick, where the demons fight in an underground fight club.
Was this a big budget Hollywood movie? A low budget B Movie? English? Were there any recognizable people in it?

Yes, english. Probably low budget hollywood. I don't remember the actors (I was 8/10 years old when I used to see it) but there aren't any major hollywood stars like Van Damme, or Schwarzanegger. More like Lorenzo Lamas type for the good guy and Dolf Lundgreen type for the villain.

@Steve-O - maybe if you expanded your search to include matches that were really, really bad movies, more Van Damme films would show up.  Or did I read that wrong?  :P

@PoloHoleSet Well, I can't really say you're wrong...  Perhaps it would be better to say I mistyped. ;)

Could it be Firepower (1993) ?

In the year 2007, crime has risen at an exponential rate. Once highly
  populated metropolises such as Los Angeles are no longer inhabitable.
  These cities have transformed into "Hell Zones," ruled by violent
  street gangs. The Hell Zone, formerly called the "Zone of Personal
  Freedom," is a safe-haven for criminal warpaths everywhere. This Hell
  Zone in LA is controlled by a criminal mastermind named Drexal (Joseph
  Ruskin). For the sake of entertaining his crowds of decadent losers
  and underlings, Drexal has staged a series of lethal, no-holds-barred
matches in the "Death Ring," where the winner takes all of the
  glory...while the defeated one shall lose his self-respect (or maybe
  just his head). Meanwhile, two brave cops, Braniff (Chad McQueen), and
  Sledge (Gary Daniels) must risk their badges...and their lives when
  they enter Los Angeles's "Hell Zone." They must fight for their lives
  in order to expose an alleged "black market" involving the sale of
  counterfeit AIDS vaccines. Will these two men triumph against all odds
  in the Hell Zone alive or will they pay with their lives?


this sounds like a really close match

It is! Thank you!

This sounds like Death Match (1994).
Similarities:
Big blonde guy.

Plot

A kickboxing champ and a reporter are searching for a missing man, but they turn up a series of illegal kickboxing matches run by an arms dealer.

There's not a lot more detail that I could find, but I think this is fairly similar.  You can find the full film on YouTube.
